# Why when i add \ to cout it dosent display it on output

Tags: c++, escaping, string-literals

When I try to do `printf("----/");`, the `\` is removed from the output

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << ("Welcome to the game\n\n");

    printf("--------\n");
    printf("----O---\n");
    printf("---/|\--\n");
    printf("---/-\--\n");
}
```

output:

```
--------
----0---
---/|--
---/---
```

Comment: Question: are you expecting the ``\`` that precedes the `n` to print out? (Hopefully not.) Why not? Why should that backslash be special, but the person's left arm and leg not be special?

Comment: Try using `---/-\\--`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has been given already: `\` is special, because it's the escape character, and you need to escape it with itself if you want a literal `\` in the outoupt.

This, however, can make the drawing confused.

To improve the things, you can use [raw strings literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

```cpp
    printf(R"(--------
----O---
---/|\--
---/-\--)");
```

Notice that I've truly inserted a line break in place of the `\n` escape sequence, because `\n` would be literally interpreted as a `\` followed by the letter `n`.

Clearly, you can still have issues, if a string contains exactly the characters `)"`, because it will be detected as the closing token of the string:

```cpp
//               +---- code invalid from here
//               |
//               v
printf(R"(-----)"---)");
```

but you can still solve it, for instance by adding another set of wrapping `"`s:

```cpp
printf(R""(-----)"---)"");
```

or anything else in between the `"` and `(`, and between `)` and `"` (**not symmetrized**):

```cpp
printf(R"xyz(-----)"---)xyz");
//                        ^
//                        |
//                        +--- not zyx
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\` character is a special one, it's the escape character. You can write special things with it (like `\n` for new line). Because this character is special, writing it to console requires using `\\`.